# do you need to clear WSAGetLastError() and if so how?

Tags: winapi, networking

In Unix, some function calls don't promise to clear `errno` so you can't detect an error by checking `errno` unless you clear it yourself before calling.  E.g.:

```
errno = 0;
some_function();
if ( errno ) {
      :
      :
```

On Windows WSAGetLastError() is used in lieu of errno.  Do all WSA functions clear the last error upon success?  Or if not, is there a way to clear it manually?  If not that either, what do you do?

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need to clear it. You only call `WSAGetLastError` if the function failed.

The normal pattern is just:

```
if (0 != WSAEventSelect(...))
{
  int error = WSAGetLastError();
  handle_error(error);
}
else
{
  WaitForSingleObject(...);
  ...
}
```

There is a [`WSASetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742209(v=vs.85).aspx) function you could call but you normally have no reason to.

Most functions on Windows are implemented so that they only set the error code on failure.

```
int WSAWhatever()
{
  BOOL success = something() && somethingelse();
  if (!success)
  {
    WSASetLastError(WSASOMETHING);
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

There are a couple of places in Win32 where you need to clear the error with `SetLastError` (`GetFileSize` etc.) but it is called out in the documentation on MSDN if required.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the function. If you find a function whose documentation tells you to call `WSASetLastError(0)` before calling the function, then do so.

However, that would be pretty rare. As with the Win32 error code (managed by `GetLastError` and `SetLastError`), the usual pattern is that you should only call `WSAGetLastError` if the function indicates that it failed. Typically failure is indicated by the return value of the function, but this varies from function to function, and the documentation should be called. The usual pattern is like so:

```
if (!some_function())
{
    int err = WSAGetLastError();
    // do something with err
}
```

Generally the function will only promise to call `WSASetLastError()` in case of failure. So the class mistake that people make is to use `WSAGetLastError()` to check for errors. That code would be like this:

```
// don't use this code, it is an anti-pattern
some_function();
int err = WSAGetLastError();
if (err != 0)
    // do something with err
}
```

You must always carefully read the documentation for each function that you call because there are quite a few different patterns in use.

Comment: Note that in modern Winsock implementations, `WSAGetLastError()` is actually just an alias for `GetLastError()`, Winsock does not implement its own independent error code for socket errors, despite the Winsock specification implying that it does. Maybe at one point, it did, but not anymore.

Comment: In the old days IE/WinInet had a registry value that let you use a custom wsock32.dll if you wanted. That and Winsock LSPs makes it almost tempting to go the other way and do `#define GetLastError WSAGetLastError` ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831568(v=ws.11) says TDI and LSPs are deprecated in Server 2012.